# How to disable GitHub Copilot X in terminal VS Code

Tags: vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I normally have a pretty good experience with Copilot X, but recently they added a feature that whenever something running on the terminal fails (including when manually terminating it with `Ctrl + C`), I get this annoying "blue stars" icon that is meant to explain the failure with Copilot. But it also inserts some kind of new line in my terminal, so, for example, if I press "arrow up" to repeat the last command (which I so often do) it writes `^[[A` instead of navigating the last commands.

[image]

If at the very least the explanations were good, it would maybe be bearable, but it doesn't even work well for that. And I can't find a way to disable just that feature, and not Copilot entirely, which I do use.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no setting for this, and maybe this is related to this API proposal (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162950#issuecomment-1668020425).

If that's the case, I suggest you to open an issue in Copilot Chat repo (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-copilot-release/issues), in order the team to be aware of the behavior you are dealing with.

Hope this helps